# Add Icon in dangerously set Inner html in React

Tags: reactjs, dangerouslysetinnerhtml

I am trying to add a icon in between string text using dangerously set inner html while div tag is working but arrow icon right (from material ui) is not working it. also noticed that it turns to lower case when actual html is rendered.

here is my code
one of the strPath is
"World->Americas->Latin America and the Caribbean"

```
let keyArray = Object.keys(selectedRegionsLocal);
    let listUI = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < keyArray.length; i++) {
        let strPath = selectedRegionsLocal[keyArray[i]].path;
        const pieces = strPath.split("->");
        let result = pieces.join(" <ArrowRightIcon></ArrowRightIcon> ")
        let fresult = '<div>' + result + '</div>';
        console.log('result ', fresult);
        listUI.push(
            <Grid dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: fresult }} />
        )
    }
    return listUI;
```

this is what i am getting in dev tools -> element section

[image]

image of actual value

[image]

what can i do to turn the above actual value to this

[image]

Comment: With `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` you can inject html not React Component, `<ArrowRightIcon>` looks like a react component. Try to use html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply put an icon on each item:

Assume that your `keyArray` is something like this:

```
const keyArray = ["World", "Americas", "South", "America"];
```

Now, you can use `map` function to add an icon for each item:

```
const result = data.map((item, i) => (
  <div key={i}>
    <ArrowRightIcon />
    <span>{item}</span>
  </div>
));
```

[image: the result]

Now, the `result` is ready to use, with a parent `div` and `flex` style, the final result will be produced:

```
<div style={{ display: "flex" }}>{result}</div>
```

[image: final result]